# HTML: Multiple onclick Audio files, make the last one stop

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I visit this site all the time to search for solutions, but I couldn't find an answer to my question.

I want to add multiple audio files to a page. So I used the following coding. What this does is when you click one file, it starts playing the music, when you click the next file the rest will pause. That's what I wanted.

But I also want the play/pause option on each file; so when you click the "listen/pause" link for "Night Swim", it starts playing, and when you click the same link again, it will stop.

Is there any way I can do this? I'm not very handy with Javascript, I tried all sorts of other codes but nothing seems to work the way I want it.

I hope someone can help me and I hope my problem is explained correctly (I'm Dutch, I apologize for my English :S )

Here's my code:

```
<audio id="1"> 
<source src="everynight-snippet.mp3" type='audio/mpeg'>
</audio>
<audio id="2"> 
<source src="nightswim-snippet.mp3" type='audio/mpeg'>
</audio>

Every Night (<a href="#" onclick="aud_play_pause('1')">Listen/Pause</a>)
Night Swim (<a href="#" onclick="aud_play_pause('2')">Listen/Pause</a>)
```

And the script:

```
<script>
ids = new Array(2); // an array with total number of ids
function aud_play_pause(idNumber) {
var idNumber = document.getElementById(idNumber);

for(var i=0; i<ids.length; i++){
document.getElementById(i+1).pause(); // Pause all ids before playing next file.
document.getElementById(i+1).currentTime = 0; // Set the time back to zero, else it will replay from the pause point.
}

idNumber.play();
}
</script>
```

So to sum it up:

- If I click the first song (Every Night), it starts playing. When I click it again, it should stop playing.
- If I click the second song (Night Swim) while the first one plays, the first song should stop playing and the second song should start. If I click the second song again, it should stop.
- etc

Comment: So you want it if its already playing to stop if clicked?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want :D
(and still have the rest pause when you click another link...does that make sense?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if the **idNumber** audio is playing using the **currentTime** property, and start it if it is not. Otherwise, if the current one is playing you can stop all of them anyway.

```js
ids = new Array(2); // an array with total number of ids
function aud_play_pause(idNumber) {
  var clickedAudio = document.getElementById(idNumber);

  for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    if ((i + 1) == idNumber && clickedAudio.currentTime == 0) { // if it's the current one and is not playing
      clickedAudio.play(); // start it
    } else { // either not the current one, or the current one but it is playing
      document.getElementById(i + 1).pause(); // Pause all ids before playing next file.
      document.getElementById(i + 1).currentTime = 0; // Set the time back to zero, else it will replay from the pause point.
    }

  }

}
```

The way you had wrote your code though the **for** paused all elements.

Comment: This might sound very dumb, but how do I skip the currently playing one? :S

Comment: @GiuliettaRoosien I modified the answer to also check if it's the current one and start it if it's already playing. Otherwise, if the current one is already playing it should stop all of them. I hope that fits your requirements. :)

Comment: XD I'm apparently very dumb...now the first one (Every Night) plays correctly, but when I click on it, it just starts from the beginning. When I click on the second one (Night Swim), it doesn't play at all and it just stops all songs from playing... :S

Comment: that's odd, I'll try making a plunker out of it. and check it for myself. :)

Comment: ah oups.. you should be comparing with i +1 to check the current one.. or really just use ids starting from 0 instead of 1. I'll change the answer to fit. :)

Comment: Yaaa :D it works now :D Thank you so much! :D
I wish I was better at scripts, but what did I expect - I used to always just copy & paste in stead of learning from scrap. I'm getting there ^_^
Thanks again, you made my day!